# Sum of unitary transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having struggle with this question.

suppose I have two unitary matrices.

Is their sum is  normal ?

I am try to give an example to show it is not true and I can not find.

I try to proof and I reach this results:

$T$,$S$ are unitary then:

$(T+S)(T+S)^{*}=(T+S)^{*}(T+S)$

$(T+S)(T^{*}+S^{*})=(T^{*}+S^{*})(T+S)$

$(T+S)T^{*}+(T+S)S^{*}=(T^{*}+S^{*})T+(T^{*}+S^{*})S$

$TT^{*}+ST^{*}+TS^{*}+SS^{*}=T^{*}T+S^{*}T+T^{*}S+S^{*}S$

$ST^{*}+TS^{*}=S^{*}T+T^{*}S$

and I can not continue from here.

I can not tell is this equation is true or not.

and BTW

matrix is unitary iff matrix is symmetric ?

Thanks in advanced !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, symmetric matrix and unitary matrix are two unrelated concepts. It is easy to find symmetric matrices that are not unitary, and vice versa.

For an example where $T+S$ is not normal, we can take $T=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & i \\ -i & 0\end{bmatrix}$, and $S=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2\end{bmatrix}$ with $\lambda_i\bar{\lambda}_i=1$ for $i=1,2$. The calculations are omitted.

It is interesting to note however, that if both $S$ and $T$ are taken in $SU(2)$ (i.e., $2\times 2$ unitary matrices whose determinant is one), then indeed $S+T$ is normal.  One way to see this is to identify $SU(2)$ with the norm 1 elements in the Hamilton quaternion algebra ( then the *-operator corresponds to taking conjugate).  Then $$ST^*+TS^*=ST^*+(ST^*)^*=\mathrm{Tr}(ST^*),$$ and similarly $$T^*S+S^*T=\mathrm{Tr}(T^*S).$$
Now $\mathrm{Tr}(ST^*)=\mathrm{Tr}(T^*S)$.

Hmm, I guess I am only using the fact that $X+X^{-1}=\mathrm{Tr}(X)$ for any $X\in SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ using the formula $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Xue I am very sorry but in your example:$TT^{*}$ is not equal to $I$.Am I wrong ? and besides I will be glad to find a Unitary matrix that is not symmetric (I did not find)

Comment: What is your $T^*$ then?  For me $T^*$ is the transpose of the complex conjugation of $T$.

Comment: @Jiangwei_Xue I notice that you are right. but lrt me show you something and then correct is I am wrong. $S=\begin{bmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & i\end{bmatrix}$ hust like you said. well so here we have $T$ like you said and the $S$ I gave you according to your directions. now both $S$ and $T$ are unitary.but the sum of those matrices is normal, so what am I doing wrong ? can you give example for $S$

Comment: @wantTolearn, In your example, both $S$ and $S^*$ are in the center of $Mat_2(\mathbb{C})$. In other words, they commutes with all matrices. So $ST^*=T^*S$ and similarly for the other expression.  Then you get the desired equality  $ST^*+TS^*=S^*T+T^*S$. What I meant in the answer is that you can choose $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ such that the sum is not normal.  $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ is not a good choice.

Comment: @Jiangwei_Xue yes I notice that now. so I will write my matrix that represent $S$ and here it is work $S=\begin{bmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$   Thank you very much !!